# ESRI Maps for SharePoint - ArcGIS for Server Only

Tags: arcgis-server, esri-maps-sharepoint

Is there any way to use Esri Maps for SharePoint without having to go through either Portal or ArcGIS Online. I am at an organization that is very hesitant to implement Portal and programs many applications directly to ArcGIS for Server. Reading most of the docs it is clear that the advertise it as configurable through either Portal or ArcGIS Online. Has anybody found a work around to this using only ArcGIS for Server. Is a work around even necessary? I essentially am hoping to grab filters & data from other Web Parts/BCS to make heat maps Amongst other things. Any thoughts?